# Ionic 2 Slides LOCK

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, slide

I would like to lock the sliding feature (by swiping the screen) it should only work when i click the button.

Since im pretty new to typescript i can't explain how i should get this to work. I found some docs on the [ionic page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#usage).

"lockSwipes(shouldLockSwipes)" 
I think this is the code i need but i have no clue how i can include it into my IonicApp.

HTML

```
<ion-slide>
  <ion-item>
    <img src="img/question.png (click)="goToSlide1()">
  </ion-item>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
  <ion-item>
    <img src="img/clue.png (click)="goToSlide2()">
  </ion-item>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
  <ion-item>
    <img src="img/answer.png (click)="Finish()">
  </ion-item>
</ion-slide>
```

TS

```
        import {Component} from '@angular/core';
        import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
        import {Finish} from '../finish/finish';
        import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
        import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


        @Component({
            templateUrl: 'build/pages/slider/slider.html'
        })
        export class Slider {
            @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
            value = '';
            changeText(value: string) { this.value = value; }
            constructor(private navController: NavController) {

            goToSlide1() {
                this.slides.slideTo(1, 500);
            }
            goToSlide2() {
                this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
            }
            goToFinish() {
                this.navController.setRoot(Finish);
            }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the begin.

First of all your HTML should look something like this:

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
    <ion-item>
        <img src="img/question.png (click)="goToSlide1()">
    </ion-item>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
    <ion-item>
        <img src="img/clue.png (click)="goToSlide2()">
    </ion-item>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
    <ion-item>
        <img src="img/answer.png (click)="Finish()">
    </ion-item>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Then in your TS file you should use the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, because `ViewChild` components will be ready here and not before.

So your TS should look like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Finish} from '../finish/finish';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/slider/slider.html'
})
export class Slider {
    @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
    value = '';
    changeText(value: string) { this.value = value; }

    constructor(private navController: NavController) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // child is set
        this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
    }

    goToSlide1() {
        this.slides.slideTo(1, 500);
    }

    goToSlide2() {
        this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
    }

    goToFinish() {
        this.navController.setRoot(Finish);
    }    
}
```

Check the [angular 2 hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

That will do the job, happy coding.

Comment: if i use

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}

Visual Studio gives me an error ->

Property lockSwipes does not exist on type Slides.

Comment: That could be because Visual Studios doesn't has the last types version of  ionic, try with `(<any>this.slides).lockSwipes(true)` if that works on runtime   you have a types issue with VS.

Comment: Works now in Visual Studio but now i get an error.

-TypeError: this.slides.lockSwipes is not a function


Any idea ? 
Ill look around in the docs ill post the solution if i find one.

Comment: You have the latest Ionic version in your packages? That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Im using ionic version 2.2.3 since the new versions are corrupting my application.
Ill try to update, but isnt it possible to lock the swiping with that version aswell ?

Comment: It should work, the `lockSwipes` function was added on 2.0.0-rc.5

Comment: Strange i will try it again with a different code.

Also I tried updating Ionic to version 3.2.2 now and it gives me an error -Cannot find module '@ionic/app-scripts' (i know different topic).

Comment: A lot of things changed since 2.2.3, check the upgrade references in the changelog, https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

I am Using Ionic version 3 with that I did something like this

In HTML

```
<ion-slides #mySlider> 
  <ion-slide class="swiper-no-swiping">Content 1 </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="swiper-no-swiping">Content 2 </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

IN TS File

```
@ViewChild('mySlider') mySlider: Slides;

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.mySlider.lockSwipes(true);
}
```

Please Note : In html need to add "swiper-no-swiping" for each slide this will disable the swapping

Answer (score 0):

add this into ionViewDidLoad  function

> ```
> ionViewDidLoad() {
>     this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
> }
> ```